# Rewrite and redirect dynamic url to static url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite my URL structure from dynamic to static. My **all URL structure are same**, so i want a standard .htaccess rule which can apply to all. I have tried various rule couldn't find appropriate rule. I hope you guys will help me, in order to get the solution of my query.

From: http://www.hemolyticanemia.org/page.php?pid=2&slug=about-us

To: http://www.hemolyticanemia.org/about-us/

Comment: When you want a rule to apply to all URL's, you'll have to describe the pattern of those url's and the intended transformation, rather than just provide an example.

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can help fix the code, we can't fix something we cant see

Comment: update my question.

Comment: Got no reply from you, i have updated my question as per your suggestion.